# Minor difficulties with Ajax and PHP interaction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I working in CodeIgniter and I am trying to spit out all of the items I have in a table and order them as they should be using the dropdown. I want it to happen without page reload and without submit buttons, so I am using this jQuery function to make  immediately react, when it is changed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".order-by-select").click(function() {var orderValue = this.value;
    $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/index", {val: orderValue}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Inside you can see the $.post method, with wich I am trying to send the data to php script (orderValue).
After that, I am getting an alert (not even sure, why do I need it (Maybe to check if everything is ok there))

In PHP, I am receiving the chosen select option and assigning a variable (`$data['people']`) to the results of MySQL query (that is placed in the model) to  be able to access it withing the view. This - `$_POST['val']` represents, how can I order the list (`select * from people order by $theorder"` ($theother is just a variable inside the query function. It recieves the value of `$_POST['val']`)).

```
if(isset($_POST['val'])) {
    $data['people'] = $this->database->listPeople($_POST['val']);
    exit;
}
```

After that I recieve this variable in the view and I am running foreach loop to take different parts of the array(name of the person, his age, etc..) and placing it in the way they should be.

The problem is - if I do that without ajax, when I have static order by value - everything works fine. I did not mean that was the problem :D, the problem basically is that is doesn't work with ajax... I was trying to recieve the array in the js callback and create a layout using

```
$.each(eval(data), function() {
  $('#container').text('<div>' + eval(res).name + '</div>');
});
```

But that was also a failure...

How should I organize and create my code to make everything work properly?

I am kinda new to Ajax, so I hope I'll really learn how to do that from you guys. I already searched through the whole internet and have seen a lot of ajax tutorials and other kind of material (e. g. StackOverflow), but I still can't get, how can I do all of that in my particular situation. I have wasted already about 12 hours trying to solve the problem and couldn't do that, so I hope You will tell me if there is any useful salvation.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: for starter, you can order by like this `SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY '$theorder' DESC` Or `SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY '$theorder' ASC`

Comment: so basically you need to order by your records?You can order by in codigniter using `$this->db->order_by('field','asc');`

Comment: Yes, I need to order by records (the <option> values). Speaking about DESC and ASC, they are a part of <option> values. The question is about ajax and php communication, I understand how CodeIgniter and MySQL queries work.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I need to order depending on the <option> a person chose. I know how to order statically (e. g. by default I have order by id asc). If I had problems with the model, I would write this post about MySQL queries. But the problem is with the Ajax and PHP communication. How to pass the variable, by witch everything should be ordered, and order the results by this variable.

Comment: _"...It doesn't work with ajax..."_ and _"But that was also a failure"_ -- HOW? You must provide more details on how it's failing and what you have done to debug/troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Jim, I was confused by all the responses I got from PHP and was struggling for 12 hours to make it right. I was trying a lot of different techniques, You think I remember which of them failed which way? I am new to Ajax. Actually, as I remember, I was confused about types of data that I recieved and couldn't make it display in html properly for each element.

Comment: first off this is a syntax error, `$(".order-by-select").click(function() {var orderValue = this.value;` where is the closing `});` on the click event?  Not to mention that `this.value` is not jQuery, it would be `$(this).val()` last I checked, just saying.

Comment: I guess I forgot that while rewriting it to StackOverflow... Actully this.value works fine, you can try it out yourself.

Comment: and you are not outputting anything from php side, just calling `exit;` unless  you missed that too.  Shouldn't you have `Header("Content-Type: application/json");` and `echo json_encode( $data )` then you don't need eval(data)

Comment: After defining the $data variable, I am sending it to the view (I just thought that was obvious).

Comment: sending what to the view, your ajax response, I hope not, because your response should be json.  I mean if you are not returning json for your ajax how do you expect data to have anything in it?  Surly it cant be your whole page

Comment: I was receiving the response in the callback, but that didn't help much. I have sent the $data variable to the view, but the page wan't changing dynamically...

Comment: Well i think you are going about it all wrong, you don't send ajax and expect a page that is loaded already to magically change, the basic way to do this is to return the select element only and then replace it.

Comment: Can you please provide any example for me to understand better? Should I get the results of the query within the callback and then to work with them from there? If yes, then how? How can I make those results place the items in the desired order?

Comment: can you provide the value of the ajax response,  I think we are a long way from understanding how ajax works.

Comment: Ok, It is a json string `[{"id":"1","name":"Nick","age":"18"},{"id":"2","name":"John","age":"23"}]`

Comment: No that is a json string, It will be easier to just replace the select entirely though

Comment: never mind I mean the table

Comment: So how can I display them one after another? I have already php foreach loop setted up... Can I send it somehow to PHP to use it or do I need to do that in the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the skinny is you need 3 parts to make ajax work,

- serverside code to generate the page
- ajax ( clientside ) to make the call and respond
- seperate serverside to receive it.

Also it will be easier to replace the table completely then to pick out elements.  But that is up to you.

So say we have the page with our ajax call

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".order-by-select").click(function() {var orderValue = this.value;
    $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/index", {val: orderValue}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Now you seem to have some json response I'll assume you get this from the alert above;

```
 [{"id":"1","name":"Nick","age":"18"},{"id":"2","name":"John","age":"23"}]
```

I'll also assume that this comes from something like

```
echo json_encode( array( array('id'=>1, ...), array('id'=>2 ...) .. );
```

It's important before doing the echo that you tell the server that this is json, you do this using a header, but you cannot output anything before the header, and after the json header all output must be in the json format or it wont work, it's like telling the browser that this is html, or an image etc. what the content is.

```
  Header("Content-Type: application/json");
  echo json_encode( ....
```

You can get away without doing this sometimes, but often you'll need to use eval or something, by telling the browser its json you don't need that.  Now doing an alert is great and all but if you see the string data `[{"id": ..` your header is wrong, you should get something like `[object]` when you do the alert.

No once we have a factual Json object we can make use of all that wonderful data

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".order-by-select").click(function() {var orderValue = this.value;
    $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/index", {val: orderValue}, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,v){
            alert(v.id);
            alert(v.name);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This should loop through all the data and do 2 alerts, first the id then the name, right.  Next it's a simple matter of replacing the content using `.text()` or `.append()`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".order-by-select").click(function() {var orderValue = this.value;
    $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>welcome/index", {val: orderValue}, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,v){
           $('#test').append('<p>'+v.id+'</p>');
        });
    });
});
</script>

<p id="test" ></p>
```

Comment: Yes, Sure. That is what I have. So if this is the right way, how can I display all of those elements? For example to pass parameters for each element (name, age, etc..) in the html format? `<div class="name">Name</div>` Like this. And to do that for every parameters and for every person?

Comment: I'm getting to that, if its a string, and not json object then it wont work.

Comment: ok, well.. I was getting the object in the beginning but after that converted it to the string... Well, thank you for explaining that. Should I append html code right from the callback?

Comment: Wow, Thanks a lot to you. I can't thank you enough for your answer. Thanks a lot! You really saved me)) Sorry, cant rate your answer - need 15 reputation for that )))